# SideMenu doesn't show when returning from submenu

Tags: ios, swift, side-menu

I'm using [SideMenu by jonkykong](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) in my app. So far I love it. It's the best and most simple to implement SideMenu I found. However I can't seem to get it to behave like I want. I'm sure it's possible, just havent figured out how and can't seem to find the answer in the documentation and here on SO.

I have a side menu (tableViewController). I can bring it up by tapping a hamburger button in my initial view controller. This works. When I tap one of the rows in the side menu, another ViewController is opened full screen, which is what I want. So far so good.

When I tap the back button in that viewcontroller, I'm returned to my initial view controller (where the hamburger button is to bring up the side menu), however now the side menu is hidden again. What I'd like is, when I push that backbutton , I'm returned to my initial view controller with the sidemenu open (the state it was before I went to that viewcontroller).

I've tried with several menuPushStyles, but none of them does this. The closest is .submenu, but that results in my initial view controller staying visible on the edge of the screen and the submenu replacing the side menu (so not full screen).

I'm almost sure there must be a way to do this, but how?